# how to handle marketplace discovery strategy failed with an error in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, testing, automated-tests, frameworks, data-driven-tests

Eclipse: eclipse marketplace is not working properly.
I  am  trying  installing  TestNG  &  Cucumber plugin on  Eclipse, But when  i  search  TestNG in find textbox  &  enter  it  is  showing  me  error  like  marketplace  discovery  strategy  failed.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the solr server providing the search feature. It has been solved and should be back online. https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipsefdn/helpdesk/-/issues/4397#note_1890412